# GAE gqlquery with variables

Tags: google-app-engine, gqlquery

If i want to run a GqlQuery with a variable i've set is that possible?

for example:

```
myNumber = 4

myResult = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * from myData WHERE filter = myNumber")
```

this results in:

> Parse Error: Invalid WHERE condition at symbol

Am i going about this all wrong?  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [The Google Appengine Documentation](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlqueryclass.html), your code might look like this:

```
myNumber = 4
myResult = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM myData WHERE filter = :num", num=myNumber)
```

or

```
myNumber = 4
myResult = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM myData WHERE filter = :1", myNumber)
```

depending on whether you want to use a named or positional variable.

Comment: Also db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM myData WHERE filter = %d" % myNumber)

Comment: @DaveW.Smith NO! This is a great way to introduce GQL injection vulnerabilities, and has absolutely no advantages over proper parameter substitution.

Comment: @NickJohnson %s would be problematic. %d isn't. Show me an exploit that works with %d.

Comment: @DaveW.Smith You're right - but it's still broken and a bad idea, and sets a bad precedent.

Comment: Not broken, but close enough to something that is that you have a good point.